# Assigning an object of flow type SuperType to SubType causes error

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I was under the impression that an inexact object type in Flow can be supplied an object with properties not declared in the type as long as all the properties that *have* been declared in the type are present.

An inexact object type declaration in Flow indicates that "the object can have any of these properties, plus any more unspecified". So an object of type SubType should be able to be assigned an object of type SuperType and still be valid.

What am I missing here?

I believe it has something to do with nested object types, but if I can't modify the undeclared properties on the genericPlan (SubType) why should it matter?

```
/* @flow */
type SuperType = {
  plan: {
    id: string,
    location: {
      id: string,
      team: {
        id: string,
      },
    },
  },
};

type SubType = {
  plan: {
    id: string,
    location: {
      id: string,
    },
  },
};

const planWithTeam: SuperType = {
  plan: {
    id: '',
    location: {
      id: '',
      team: {
        id: '',
      },
    },
  },
};

// The following throws this error:
// Cannot assign planWithTeam to genericPlan because property team is 
// missing in SubType [1] but exists in SuperType [2] in property plan.location.
const genericPlan: SubType = planWithTeam;
```

Comment: change name `Plan` => `GenericPlan `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [nested object props are invariant by default](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/depth-subtyping/). To make in covariant just add a plus sign:

```
type SubType = {
  +plan: {
    id: string,
    +location: {
      id: string,
    },
  },
};
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwDKArngE4AqO+AvGAN6phjYwCGAdgFz2NNgCWAE24BndKX7sA5gBpeTeAGNW6fnC48+fIaPGTZ8vulysAttwZatOsGInS5VsAF9HfV7w-OA3KgxVCIgAjSjwwWkswAGoWDgtDGzt9NyYopRU1DUjrYVs9B0MPJi9fVEV1MWY2dgB1fnQAC3ITc0CyUJpNKriuphsAcn6UsHTVdXinAaHDJmMzCacBXMHh4uGilzkfP2BgMHIG-Cg4GHgEfTBG0kQRS4b+W9xSa9JOVF2wAGEOdjh0MFYIhE-Ck7G6tXqTRalzgYCkuHYT34igACtUwEFcMoiCJ8NhrmQsJdoQ8wO89qYHsDpAIwcQQgEANoARgAuhiiP9cAAPB7oW6SNpPDpgRkAJnZgvxcEJmHBADpRpl5WUKv94YiJKjqtx6SLaLEIY1mmZvEA)